# Transition on conditional rendering in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this conditional render function ready and it works fine.

```
 render() {
    if (this.state.guess === 'guessing') {
        return (
            <div style={rightBarStyle.guessingGameStyle}>
                <div style={rightBarStyle.guessingGameStyle.quizBlockStyle}>
                    <h3> Who is this? </h3>
                    <ul className={'optionsContainer'}>
                        <PeopleNames onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}/>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div style={rightBarStyle.guessingGameStyle.imgBlockStyle}>
                    <img style={rightBarStyle.guessingGameStyle.imgBlockStyle.image} src={imageLink}
                         alt={"profile pic"}/>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
    else if (this.state.guess === 'correct') {
        return (
            <div style={rightBarStyle.guessingGameStyle}>
                <div style={rightBarStyle.guessingGameStyle.quizBlockStyle}>
                    <FadeIn>
                        <p className={['details','title'].join(' ')}>{name} </p>
                        <p className={['details','designation'].join(' ')}>Software Developer</p>
                        <p  className={['details','team'].join(' ')}>Software Department</p>
                    </FadeIn>
                </div>
                <div style={rightBarStyle.guessingGameStyle.imgBlockStyle}>
                    <img style={rightBarStyle.guessingGameStyle.imgBlockStyle.image} src={imageLink}
                         alt={"profile pic"}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    else return <div></div>
}
```

Issues:

1. I need to apply a transition whenever new DOM elements are rendered on state change. I read about CSSTransitions but they work on child elements.
   Here is the sandbox link on which I want to have a smooth transition onclick of the button: [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/885vq6pr92)
2. I have to include that last 'else' otherwise it throws an error that render didn't find anything to be rendered on DOM. It works but is there a workaround for this? It does not look neat.

Comment: is there any guess value other than `guessing` and `correct` ?

Comment: No not yet. The case where the user is wrong is handled in the guessing state. In fact he has to guess until he gets the right answer.